# filtering objects based on boolean field state

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I'm working on a project where a form is filled out. And in that form you have the is_active fields. If the user selects True, it means the account is active and if it is False, it means it is no longer active, and the user can no longer see it. Through the filters I'm trying to present only the forms with the is_active True, but I'm not able to.

Follow one of my attempts in my views:

```
class BookingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    #queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    #queryset = Booking.objects.filter(is_active="True")
    #filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    #filterset_class = BookingFilter
    #filterset_fields = ['is_active']


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Booking.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('bookings')
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(is_active__username=username)
        return queryset
```

and here are my models

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    booking_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, models.DO_NOTHING)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, models.DO_NOTHING)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    from_city = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    to_city = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    travel_date = models.DateField()
    travel_period = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    adults_travelers_count = models.SmallIntegerField()
    children_travelers_count = models.SmallIntegerField()
    senior_travelers_count = models.SmallIntegerField()
    booking_request_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    booking_status_cd = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    locator_code = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    total_booking_price_atm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    total_booking_cost_atm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    payment_type_cd = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    payment_status_cd = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    payment_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    discount_percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    discount_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    payment_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    voucher_file_path = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    receipt_file_path = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    invoice_file_path = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_ts = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    modified_op = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

 class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'booking'
        unique_together = (("booking_id", "account", "tenant"),)
```

Comment: Hm where is username here? Is that on the account model perhaps? Or the tenant model?

Comment: it's actually just the variable name that I didn't change when I got it from the Django Rest Framework documentation

Comment: Ok you cannot filter by a field that you do not have declared on one of your models. If you just want active bookings, `Booking.objects.filter(is_active=True)` will give you that. If you somehow need to filter by user, that requires you to know how a user is connected to the `Booking` model.

Comment: But do I put this inside my function? In which part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you're correct that the filter `Booking.objects.filter(is_active=True)` will give you all the active bookings. If you also want to filter by username, you need to have another filter (can comma-separate in the same filter function) to filter by that. It's unclear where `username` lives in your models, but assuming it's on the account model:

`Booking.objects.filter(is_active=True, account__username=username)`

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = []
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        bookings = Bookings.objects.all()
        for i in bookings:
            if i.is_active
                queryset.append(i)
    return queryset
```

This should do it!!

Comment: While this would work technically, as in not throw an error and presumably get you all the active bookings, it would not filter by user and it is doing an unnecessary python loop to give essentially what `Bookings.objects.filter(is_active=True)` would do. ETA it also does not return a queryset, it returns a list.